# Fatal error while loading a workspace in RStudio

Tags: rstudio, fatal-error

I have a saved workspace in the project directory. The workspace image size is 4GB and I have a RAM of 8GB.

I can't load the workspace image. The RStudio is crashing after running for sometimes either aborting with fatal error message or showing memory error.

I just tried to load... it's supposed to load the workspace.

Comment: Do you want the data in the workspace or you just want Rstudio to load?

Comment: I want the data in the workspace. R studio opens well with all scripts as it was but can't load the workspace

Comment: "*either aborting with fatal error message or showing memory error.*" Please include the details/contents of these error messages in your question.